# Knockout databind change text color by background color contrast

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have a table with informations from my database:

The ViewModel:

```
function alertViewModel(i) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(i.Id);

self.AlertType = ko.observable(i.AlertType);
self.Category = ko.observable(i.Category);
self.Color = ko.observable(i.Color);
self.AlertText = ko.observable(i.AlertText);
self.update = function (data) {
    if (typeof (data.AlertType) != 'undefined') self.AlertType(data.AlertType);
    if (typeof (data.Category) != 'undefined') self.Category(data.Category);
    if (typeof (data.Color) != 'undefined') self.Color(data.Color);
}
};
```

In the cshtml I display the data like this:

```
<table class="table" id="alertstable">
                                <tbody data-bind="foreach: alerts">
                                    <tr data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: Color }">
                                        <td>
                                            <b data-bind="text: AlertText">Message</b>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Each table row can have different background color and depending on that color contrast the text color should change in black or white like in this code:

```
function getContrastYIQ(hexcolor){
    var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(0,2),16);
    var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(2,2),16);
    var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(4,2),16);
    var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
    return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
}
```

It is possible to change the text color using this function? Please help me with it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You could add a [Knockout Computed Observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for the text color to the viewmodel (like "TextColor").

This computed should be dependent on the existing Color observable and could make use of the mentioned function. Something like:

```
self.TextColor = ko.computed(function() {
    return getContrastYIQ(self.Color());
});
```

Finally add a color binding to the current style binding on tr:

```
databind="style: { backgroundColor: Color, color: TextColor }"
```

Comment: I've made the changes as you said, but now it doesn't return any alert from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer for it after some research:

1. In the viewmodel I added this line:

   self.TextColor = ko.observable(i.TextColor);
2. Where I load the viewmodel with the database informations:

   element['TextColor'] = getContrastYIQ(element.Color);
3. In the cshtml file I added:

   databind="style: { backgroundColor: Color, color: TextColor }"
4. I changed the getContrastYIQ() function like this:

   function cutHex(h) {
       return (h.charAt(0) == "#") ? h.substring(1, 7) : h
   }

   function HexToR(h) {
       return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(0,2),16)
   }

   function HexToG(h) {
       return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(2, 4), 16)
   }

   function HexToB(h) {
       return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(4, 6), 16)
   }

   function getContrastYIQ(hexcolor) {
       var r = HexToR(hexcolor);
       var g = HexToG(hexcolor);
       var b = HexToB(hexcolor);
       var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
       return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
   }

and it works perfectly for me. Hope it helps others!